# Problem with babel and tailwindcss in Next.js: Cannot find module 'xwind/babel'

Tags: reactjs, next.js, babeljs

I installed tailwindcss inside of my Next.js application. This was the error message that I received

```
error - ./node_modules/next/dist/client/dev/amp-dev.js
Error: Cannot find module 'xwind/babel'
```

This is how I installed the Next.js application:

```
npx create-next-app -e with-tailwindcss ./
```

These are the dependencies I installed:

```
npm install graphql graphql-request html-react-parser moment react-multi-carousel sass
```

Comment: Same problem for me. I wonder if it is a new version of something that is causing it.

Answer (score 2):

Happened to me as well just few minutes ago. Not sure if that is the same case for you. It created for me `components` folder, .babelrc file and js files in pages folder. Not sure if that is your case, but that's what happened to me. In case just follow with solution below.

## Solution

Remove `.bablerc` file and `components` folder along with js files in `pages` folder.

## More details

This is strange because if you look at the [repository](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-tailwindcss) of Next.js example `with-tailwindcss`. It doesn't have those. Not sure how that happened. We can elaborate more in the comments.

Also plugin for babel `xwind/babel` does have dependency check to allow only `tailwindcss` version <2. There is an [issue](https://github.com/Arthie/xwind/issues/34) for that. In my opinion this repo is unmaintained and will either get forked and replaced as a main for npm package or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

The create-next-app is installing `with-tailwind-emotion` template instead of `with-tailwind` for some reason.

For now, a good way is to create a normal typescript template with create-next-app and add tailwind manually.

So your steps would be:

Step 1:
without typescript:

```
npx create-next-app ./
```

or with typescript:

```
npx create-next-app --ts ./
```

Step 2:

Docs to install tailwind with next.js:
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs

Comment: Happened to me too. I added a comment to an open ticket https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/45814